# accessibility text for switch view reads as " switch checked" and "switched not checked" if the textOn and textOff is empty

Tags: android, accessibility, android-togglebutton

In my application i need to show a switch view with no text , i am using below code.

```
    <Switch
                android:id="@+id/switchsample"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:checked="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:switchPadding="0dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textOff=""
                android:textOn=""
                android:textSize="@dimen/wifi_on_off_font"
                android:visibility="visible" />
```

The issue is when accessibility enabled ,it reads as "switch checked" if ON mode and reads as "switch not checked".

I have checked with native switch button ( example wifi ON/OFF in settings ) it reads as "Switch ON" and "Switch OFF". Same thing i am expecting in my application ,but it is not working as expected.

One more thing i have noticed is when i remove below it reads as "Switch ON" and "Switch OFF".

```
                android:text=""
                android:textOff=""
                android:textOn=""
```

But the draback is it adds ON/OFF text in the switch view ..In my application i want to show the switch button without ON/OFF text and it should read as "Switch ON" and "Switch OFF" when accessibility enable.